# Need Help Sending Email Through Office 365 SMTP with Custom Domain

Tags: django, authentication, email, smtp, office365

I need to be able to send emails to users from `support@example.com` which is hosted in office365.My project's setting file for the email backend looks like this

```
# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.office365.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "support@example.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "App_password"
```

The specific error message I'm currently facing is [`Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator.`]

I have verified the login credentials and also tried both ports `587` and `25`, but the issue remains unresolved.

### **However, **

I was able to send emails successfully using `smtp-mail.outlook.com` with an `@outlook.com` email address

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "personal@outlook.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "App_password"
```

I don't think this has anything to do with it but function that sends the email.

```
def send_email_verification(user):
    site_url = "https://www.example.com"
    print("Trying to send email")

    if user.is_active:
        return
    else:
        print("sending email")
        confirmation_token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)  # unique token
        activation_link = f"{site_url}/users/api/users/activate/{user.id}/{confirmation_token}"   # activation link to be sent in email

        subject = "Verify your Email address"
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = user.email


        # Load the email template and render it with the activation link
        html_content = render_to_string('email_verification.html', {'activation_link' : activation_link})
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)         # This strips the html, so people will have the text.


        # Create the email, message and send it.
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to_email])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

        try:
            msg.send()
            print(f"Email successfully sent to {user.email}")
            print(f"confirmation toke = {confirmation_token}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"an error  has occured while sending email : {e}")
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice, insights, or possible solutions from those who might have encountered a similar issue before. Your help would be immensely valuable. Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score -1):

Office 365 no longer allows Basic authentication. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission